# defaultManagerSettings not in scope in Network.HTTP.Conduit

Tags: haskell, http-conduit

In [http-conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit) version 2.0+ I want to create a custom `Manager`.

The documentation states that `defaultManagerSettings` should be used in `newManager`.

```hs
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
main = do manager <- newManager defaultManagerSettings
          print $ content
```

However, when trying to run it I get the following error:

```
conduittest.hs:3:33:
    Not in scope: `defaultManagerSettings'
    Perhaps you meant `conduitManagerSettings' (imported from Network.HTTP.Conduit)
```

Shall I use `conduitManagerSettings` instead? If not, where can I import `defaultManagerSettings` from?

*Note:* This question intentionally does not show further research effort, because it was immediately answered in a Q&A-style manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As listed in the [`newManager` docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.0.0.3/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#v%3anewManager), you can import `defaultManagerSettings` like this:

```hs
import Network.HTTP.Client (defaultManagerSettings)
```

Let's have a look what `conduitManagerSettings` is:

```hs
conduitManagerSettings :: ManagerSettings
conduitManagerSettings = tlsManagerSettings
```

In `Network.HTTP.Client.TLS`, [`tlsManagerSettings`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-tls-0.2.0.2/docs/src/Network-HTTP-Client-TLS.html#tlsManagerSettings) is defined as follows:

```
tlsManagerSettings :: ManagerSettings
tlsManagerSettings = mkManagerSettings def Nothing
```

Ok, so nothing special here. `def` is from the `Data.Default` module and therefore defines the default instance. However [`defaultManagerSettings`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.2.0.3/docs/src/Network-HTTP-Client-Manager.html#defaultManagerSettings) specifies all default values.

I wasn't able to track down where the `instance Default ManagerSettings` resides. However I think it is safe to assume that `mkManagerSettings def Nothing` has the same settings as `defaultManagerSettings`.

I personally recommend to use `defaultManagerSettings`, because any of these behaviours might change in the future.